# Eclipse / Android raw txt file error (Content is not allowed in prolog)

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, text-files

I need to place a raw `*.txt`  file in my android-project to read from it and output general terms and conditions in a dialog.
However, Eclipse shows, that my `.txt` file contains errors (see title). It's not an xml file and should be treated like a raw file. Why the error?!?! How can i fix it?

Thanks in advance.

**Solved:**

1. Eclipse restarting does NOT help.
2. Creating a file with the eclipse 'New File'-Wizard on the raw folder helps. It's kind of a bug.

*DONT:* Create a file in another folder and put it in the res/raw folder afterwards. Eclipse doesn't recognize the file has been move to a folder where problems should be ignored. Alittle buggy tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like it is interpreting it as an XML file;  is it in res/raw or assets/ ?  Non-xml resources should be put in one of those two project directories.

Comment: yeah.. i wanted to add, its in `res/raw`. Even if i put it in `assets` nothing changes.

Comment: even if i have solved my own problem i will accept your answer as a reminder for other people with a similar problem. ~ thank you